# Java JNI GetStringUTFChars

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am learning Java JNI and trying to understand the GetStringUTFChars & ReleaseStringUTFChars. Still i can't able to understand the ReleaseStringUTFChars.
As per my understanding from some article, in most cases that the GetStringUTFChars return a reference to the original string data and not a copy. So actually the ReleaseStringUTFChars release the jstring or the const char* (if copied) or both.

I can get a better understanding if i get the answer to the below question.

In the below code do i need to call the ReleaseStringUTFChars in a for loop or only once (with any one of the const char*)?

```
#define array_size 10
const char* chr[array_size];
jboolean blnIsCopy;
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    chr[i] = env->GetStringUTFChars(myjstring, &blnIsCopy);
    printf((bool)blnIsCopy ? "true\n" : "false\n"); //displays always true
    printf("Address = %p\n\n",chr[i]); //displays different address
}

//ReleaseStringUTFChars with in a for loop or single statement is enough
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(myjstring, chr[i]);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get 10 times "StringUTF8Chars" hence need 10 releases. I take it that the pointers are different? Or copy once in this artificial example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get/ReleaseStringUTFChars` must always be called in pairs, regardless of whether a copy or not is returned.

In practice, you pretty much always get a copy (at least with the JVM implementations I checked: OpenJDK and Dalvik) so that the GC is free to move the original array. *It obviously can't collect it because you've got a reference to the string but it'll still move objects around.*

There is also a **`GetStringCritical/ReleaseStringCritical`** call pair, which will always attempt to return a pointer to the original array (though in theory it may still return a copy). This makes it faster but it comes at a cost: the GC must not move the array until you release it. Again, in practice this is usually implemented by establishing a mutex with the GC, and incrementing a lock count for `Get` and decrementing it for `Release`. This means **these must be called in pairs too**, otherwise the lock count will never get back to zero and GC will probably never run. **Please note: `Get/ReleaseStringCritical` also comes with other limitations which are less relevant to this question but are no less important.**